# Add a word before last word in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to add a word before last word of sentence.

Example :

```
   t1 = "Top Senior Players" OR t1 = "Top Athlete" OR t1 = "Youngest Athlete"
   t2 = "Hockey"  OR t2 = "Cricket" etc.
```

I wish to get output like

```
   var game = "Top Senior <t2> Players" OR t1 = "Top  <t2> Athlete" OR t1 = "Youngest  <t2>  Athlete"
```

It should be at word before last word .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 'first third'
a.split(' ').insert(-2, 'second').join(' ')
=> "first second third"

a = 'first'
a.split(' ').insert(-2, 'second').join(' ')
=> "second first"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
t1.split(" ").insert(-2,t2).join(" ")
```